# Erlang - checking for unbound variables

Tags: variables, testing, binding, erlang

Is there any way to know if a certain variable has been bound or not after an expression has been evaluated ?

My code:

```
{ok, After} = ts_dynvars:lookup(last, DynVars),
```

what I need to know if whether there is any "After" to work with or not. Perhaps that "ok" can be put to use for my purpose ?

Thanks!

Comment: In what situation would `After` not be bound in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you (try to) refer to an unbound variable in an expression, it's a compilation error. In particular, after

```
{ok, After} = ts_dynvars:lookup(last, DynVars),
```

there are only two possibilities: if the pattern matches, `After` *is* bound, and can be used; if it doesn't, an exception will be thrown, and code which tries to work with `After` will never be executed.

UPDATE:

> are you telling me there is no way to branch code execution in the situation in which the pattern does not match

Of course there is:

```
case ts_dynvars:lookup(last, DynVars) of
  {ok, After} -> ...;
  _ -> ... %% or other patterns
end
```

but the compiler won't let you use `After` in other branches or after `case` (unless *all* branches bind `After`).

> is this exception not catchable at all

It is:

```
try
  {ok, After} = ts_dynvars:lookup(last, DynVars),
  ...
catch
  _:_ -> ...
end
```

but again, you won't be able to use `After` in `catch` sections or after `try` ends (you can bind a *new* variable named `After`, of course).

Comment: are you telling me there is no way to branch code execution in the situation in which the pattern does not match ? i.e. is this exception not catchable at all ?

Answer (score 1):

3 possibilities:

- `After` is not yet bound and the `ts_dynvars:lookup/2` returns a result of
  the form `{ok,Value}` then `After` is bound to `Value` (a copy is made)
  and the program goes to the next line.
- `After` is already bound and `ts_dynvars:lookup/2` returns exactly `{ok,After}`: the pattern matches;
  `After` keeps its value; and the program goes to the next line.
- `ts_dynvars:lookup/2` returns `Ret` that does not match `{ok,After}` as
  described in the 2 previous lines. Then the execution stops and the
  VM throws the exception `{badmatch,Ret}`. If the line is in a `catch` or
  a `try` section, the process will continue, otherwise it will crash. The next
  line of code (if any) will never be executed.